# Should I post about a problem that was solved without knowing how?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently ran into an issue trying to install the [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/) addon for Google Chrome. It gave me an error message I'd never seen before. (*Error: Line 1, column 1, Unexpected token*). I was able to reproduce the issue 3 separate times.

As I was writing up my issue, I tried to install LastPass again to verify the issue. To my surprise, the addon installed without any issues on the 4th try.

I'm still not sure what caused the error to happen, or why the install worked on the 4th attempt.

**Should I still post my question if I don't know what caused the issue or how it was solved?**

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, no one is going to be able to diagnose it. And since you got it working, there's no benefit in someone spending time and effort even trying.

Comment: Sounds more like something you should submit as a bug report to the creator of the addon, rather than asking about on SE.

Comment: Doesn't sound like it would be useful.  Whenever something fails after being installed, reinstallation is one of the universally applicable troubleshooting methods.  Nothing unique about this situation.